# How can I build a nested grid of photos in Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0m142c4/

I am trying to use foundation's grid to build a grid of photos.

I want it to look like this with all of the blocks representing photos.
[image]:

I am, as foundation's documentation suggests, nesting two columns inside of one column, and the third column just contains its image.

HTML:

```
           <div class="row grid-row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns grid-img port">
                        <img src="img/tile1-new.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns grid-img land">
                        <img src="img/tile7.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-4 columns grid-img land">
                        <img src="img/tile3.jpg" />

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns grid-img">
                        <img src="img/tile7.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-4 columns grid-img">
                        <img src="img/tile3.jpg" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-img{
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-img img{
    min-width:90%;
}

.grid-img.port img{
    min-width:100%;
}

.grid-row{
    height:600px;
}
```

But it's coming out like this instead:

[image]

Any idea how to get the images to fill their nested columns and maintain a padded grid like my example?

Comment: Use `large-6` inside the row container instead of `large-4` as they should take half the width each. However, your images are wider than they are tall so you will either have to switch to background images or use some sort of masking to get them to switch and keep aspect ratio. Probably also have to use the equal heights plugin  for your columns unless you are able to hard code the min-height of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close, you needed to use 100% width for the images and then change large-4 columns to large-6 as they were never going to take up 50% each which they needed to do.

You can now tweak bottom margin to make the layout work a little bit better. There's a really geeky way to do this which is Masonry.js or Isotope.js, it resizes containers, but might be a bit heavy handed to do what html and css can do pretty well. See below:

```css
/*.grid-img {
  text-align: center;
}
.grid-img img {
  min-width: 90%;
}
.grid-img.port img {
  min-width: 100%;
}
.grid-row {
  height: 600px;
}
*/

.grid-img img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.0/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row grid-row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns grid-img port">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns grid-img land">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" />
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns grid-img land">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns grid-img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" />
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns grid-img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```